# How to list all unix current process in details?

Tags: linux, unix

How do I display all current process in Unix in details and it's source files?

The report I want is similar to Daily Process Log in cPanel ex:

```
bookysma    bookysma.com    0.7     httpd [bookysma.com] [/images/Maple_Syrup.jpg]
```

Appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: what you are asking for is a little confusing given the fields in the documentation for [daily process log](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/WHMDocs/CPUusage) so you might want to provide some more detail

Answer (score 2):

A list of all the running processes can be generated using the `ps` tool like so;

```
# ps -ef 
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 May16 ?        00:00:01 /sbin/init
root         2     0  0 May16 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 May16 ?        00:00:55 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         6     2  0 May16 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]
```

...snip...

to see which files are currently open for  ALL the process you can do;

```
 # lsof -P | grep REG
 .... lots of output
```

if you want to get all the files open by some particular service such as httpd you can do something like this;

```
#  ps axo comm,pgrp | grep httpd
httpd           15791
```

and then use that process group id, to select all the files opened by httpd and its children like so;

```
# lsof -P -g 15791 | grep REG
httpd   24774 15791 apache  mem    REG    253,0     15104   141783 /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
httpd   24774 15791 apache  mem    REG    253,0    177680   171892 /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
httpd   24774 15791 apache  mem    REG    253,0    911816   171937 /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
... snip
```

Answer (score 0):

run the top command and then press c

It will list which command is running for a process.

Other than that you can alwasy redirect the all the running process information from top to a file

top -b -c -M  >

This will list all the prcesses with command and Memory in MB's so you have a clean output.

Additionally you can put this command in a script and run it according to your needs through cron.

Thanks..
Sandeep